# Google map api overlay takes controls

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlay

I'm displaying an image over the entire google map. The image is transparent. I follower the documentation from google and everything worked out fine. The image will change each time i move or zoom on the map. After a while I can't zoom or move the map anymore, I'm zooming and moving only the image. Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: How about posting a link to your map? Or at least an example of demonstrating the problem.

Comment: i will try create the same thing in jsfiddle and then get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues contributing to problems on the page:

- You are destroying and recreating your overlay on center_changed and zoom_changed events. Instead, you should just be updating the image within the overlay. You should really only need to create the overlay once.
- Instead of adding your weather image to your OverlayView, you are adding it to a `div` that covers the map. This is what is blocking your events from effecting the map (the click and drag events are occurring on your weather div not the map).

Comment: Do you know how to set the bounds of the overlay? Because i'm no longer removing the overlay and recreate it ... the same bounds remain and it's not good

Comment: From your usage and issues, it sounds like you may be more interested in a Ground Overlay: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay

Comment: It displays an image over a LatLngBounds: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#GroundOverlays